# net surgery pycaffe copy weights and reshape

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to copy the learned weights of a layer 'con_1' of size 3x3x3 of a pretrained model to a new layer 'con_1_1' such that the size of the new layer will be 6x3x3 (6 channels). I am actually trying to replicate the weights of size 3x3x3 to 6x3x3. How can I do it using pycaffe.

```
      layer name: 'con_1'
      size: 3x3x3

      new layer name: 'con_1_1'
      size: 6x3x3

      con_1_1 should be [con_1, con_1] % just concatenation of two con_1 weights
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to read the network using the .prototxt file and the .caffemodel file. Then copy the weights from the original network into a variable, and then copy them into the edited network.

```
net = caffe.Net('path/to/conv.prototxt', 'path/to/conv.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
W = net.params['con_1'][0].data[...]
b = net.params['con_1'][1].data[...]

net = caffe.Net('path/to/conv2.prototxt', 'path/to/conv2.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
W_1 = numpy.concatenate(W, W, axis=2)
b_1 = numpy.concatenate(b, b, axis=0)
net.params['con_1_1'][0].data[...] = W_1
net.params['con_1_1'][1].data[...] = b_1
```

Have a look at this [link](http://christopher5106.github.io/deep/learning/2015/09/04/Deep-learning-tutorial-on-Caffe-Technology.html) and this [link](https://gist.github.com/FranciscoCanas/844aab52fcff6b1c652a) for more information.